# How to manipulate result from diop_linear in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following simple code:

```
import sympy
from sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine import diop_linear

x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
eq = 2*x+3*y-10
sol_eq = diop_linear(eq)
```

The variable `sol_eq` is equal to `(3*t_0 - 10, 10 - 2*t_0)`. Now, I would like to be able to substitute to `sol_eq[0]` the value 1 for `t_0` and evaluate this. But if I try `sol_eq[0].subs({t_0:1})` of course I get an error as `t_0` is not defined. If I defined `t_0` as a symbol, it seems that is treating these as different.

Any suggestion? The sympy help does not seem to provide any indication on how to manipulate the result or, more precisely, I haven't been able to find out.

Comment: I just noticed that I can pass a parameter to the function. I created `t = sympy.symbols('t')` and then called `sol_eq = diop_linear(eq, t)`, but the result is in terms of `t_0`, which is still not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the symbol yourself and it will work provided you set the `integer=True` assumption:

```
In [1]: import sympy 
   ...: from sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine import diop_linear 
   ...:  
   ...: x, y = sympy.symbols('x y') 
   ...: eq = 2*x+3*y-10 
   ...: sol_eq = diop_linear(eq)                                                                                                               

In [2]: sol_eq                                                                                                                                 
Out[2]: (3⋅t₀ - 10, 10 - 2⋅t₀)

In [3]: t0 = Symbol('t_0', integer=True)                                                                                                       

In [4]: sol_eq_1 = tuple(s.subs({t0: 1}) for s in sol_eq)                                                                                      

In [5]: sol_eq_1                                                                                                                               
Out[5]: (-7, 8)
```